# Help understanding power requirements from computer datasheet

Tags: power-supply, ohms-law

I wanted some advice on how to read power specs from a datasheet. There's a computer I'm trying to power. The datasheet simply says it needs 12-19V input voltage. However, it says the buyer is provided with a 19V, 90W power adapter.

Consider that all loads from the CPU are constant:

Suppose I have a 12V regulator that I want to use instead. Does this mean that my regulator has to supply the ratio in Amperage? Am I correct in assuming that at 12V input supply voltage, the required current draw would be =90/12 ~ 7.5A?

Would this also mean that the current draw at 19V input supply voltage would be =90/19 ~ 4.7A?

Understanding this will help me size my regulator.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm inclined to say yes, in theory at least. In practice there are conversion losses that make things less linear, but the effect should be rather small, given modern converter efficiency. Can you tell us what computer it is?

Comment: @Unimportant here is a link to one of the datasheets. These NUCs all have slightly different datasheets but this form factor tends to operate on the same equipment: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/intel-nuc/NUC10i357FN_TechProdSpec.pdf

Comment: There's no mention of 12-19V supply in that document tough, only 19V.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that but some of the NUC datasheets say 12-19V and the chassis of my product says 12-19V at the input. I think it's just a sloppy datasheet. Don't think Intel would make a mistake on their enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct; match wattage between the two supplies.

Answer (score 0):

The 90 watts will be a maximum rating. It may just be the rating of a supply that the supplier happened to have/was able to get, and not really related to the computer's actual power requirement.

The actual power requirement of the computer may be considerably less, but you can only determine that by measuring the power consumption when the computer is operating.

Comment: So I should hook onto it with a multimeter or current clamp to check this?

Answer (score 0):

Just choose the same or higher wattage power supply at 12V. Since the original supply is 90W, I'd suggest buying one of the very common 12V 100W or 125W models. Use a higher-rated supply if you intend to run it in hot environment, e.g. without air conditioning, right after taking it out of a hot car, exposed to sunlight, etc.

That's about it, really.

If you want to dig a bit deeper:

Depending on circumstances, the efficiency of the internal buck power supplies in the laptop will vary with the input voltage. Given that the input voltage range is 12V to 19V, it may well be that the sweet spot for lowest heating in the laptop is around 15V. It's hard to know outright, depending on how the power supplies are implemented inside the laptop, but generally at lower input voltages, the conduction losses grow, whereas at higher input voltages, the switching losses grow. Whether the optimum is inside of the 12V to 19V range or outside of it depends on how good a job the designers did.

The typical way you'd measure it is by running some fixed benchmark continuously on the laptop, representative of your typical use case, with the screen on, and plot power consumption (voltage x current) as a function of input voltage. The input voltage with lowest power consumption is the one where the power supplies inside the laptop waste least amount of power due to inefficiency. On the other hand, the difference between the best and worst power consumption in such a test may be so small as to make it no concern. That's up to you.

In practice, you won't be wanting to need oddball power supplies, so the common values of 12V and 15V would be the only choices worth considering.